# Ajax call not returning latest data from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I'm having trouble with my ajax call not returning the latest information about the latest version of an application from Active Record. I'm running an ajax call on click of a link to run a controller method to update class variables that contain links to an external download handler, but it seems to return the previous one. When I refresh, the page, it returns the latest one, but kinda defeats the purpose of an ajax call.

Here is the .html.erb method

```
$('.download-link').on('click', function(event) {
            var id = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/updater",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location.href = "<%= @version.download_link %>"
                }
            })
        })
```

Here is the controller method that is routed to /updater:

```
def update
  @version = AppVersion.find_by(app_type: "AppType", is_active: true)
end
```

What can I do to make sure it's getting the latest version data from Active Record without having to reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

when generate `.js.erb` (which contains the ajax get the latest download-link), Rails server rendering will use current variables to fill those place holders such as `"<%= @version.download_link %>"`, so that the previous version (here is @version) will be used and the ajax code will be fixed: `window.location.href = current-download-link`, that why it always returns the previous one.

you need to update to use `result` - the success response data of the ajax call, something like this

```js
success: function (result) {
  window.location.href = result.download_link
}
```